# How to use these 6 textures ripped from a CryEngine game, with cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I have extracted a character model and textures from a game using NinjaRipper. The game is the mmorpg Aion and uses CryEngine.

I found in the generated files 6 textures for the same mesh, but I have no idea on how to combine them to get the in-game appearance :

[image]

Based on the tutorials I could find on youtube, I am kind of guessing the purpose of the ones on the left (Diffuse, normal and specular maps?), however, the other ones are a total mystery.

The character itself looks like this in-game :

[image]

Comment: What rendering engine are you intending to use?

Comment: Oh sorry, Cycles, I forgot to mention !

Comment: The ones on the right might have to do with different spec settings? Three different spec maps for three different spec materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the [Cryengine docs](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC2/Texture+Maps) section on textures isn't complete but I managed to download a model and look at some of the textures. Hopefully these educated guesses will point you in the right direction.

[image: images]

1. I'm not seeing anything that matches the texture and color of her skin,
   so that could be the game-engine vetex shader coloring the model and
   using 1 for texture details. The model I downloaded also had 1a as an
   alpha channel for the eyelashes.
2. Seems to be masking out the face to apply some effect on the lips.
   Don't know about the rest.
3. You guessed it, the normal map. This one doesn't have an alpha
   channel to handle gloss as mentioned in the Cryengine docs.
4. The eyebrows on this image don't match 1, So its possible that they
   are only using the blue parts, perhaps in combination with 2.
5. This seems to be the Unified Detail Map, Which is separate from the
   Normal map. This has an alpha channel so its controlling the glossiness.
6. Possibly for an effect in the eyeball geometry, Perhaps with the
   sclera bit in 4

With all this in mind, you may need to do a few adjustments to some textures for blender, and you don't have to use all of them. For example; Blender doesn't use alpha channels to control glossiness, you will need to make a specular map based on the Alpha channel of 5.

The exact setup will depend on whether you are using Blender Internal or Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

A full run-down of how to use textures in Cycles is a bit beyond the scope of this site. There are lots of good tutorials. BlenderGuru is a personal favorite.

In short, you'll create three texture nodes (I have no idea what the other three images on the right are for).

For one node, you'll load in the diffuse texture (top-left). That, you'll plug into the "color" slot of a diffuse shader.

For another node, you'll load in the normal map (middle-left). That, you'll plug into the "normal" slot for ALL the relevant shaders. For example, you'll probably mix together a diffuse shader with a few glossy shaders. You'll want to plug this into the "normal" slot for any of those shaders that are used on the head.

For a third node, you'll load in the spec map (bottom-left). That, you'll have to experiment with. To start with, plug it into the "color" slot of a glossy node.

Eventually, you'll want to mix your diffuse and glossy together. At that point, it may be helpful to ALSO plug the spec map into the "fac" slot of the mix shader that mixes the glossy and diffuse.

Now, this is the simplest possible setup, and it'll probably look terrible because it was designed for a different renderer. You'll want to insert some ramp nodes to control your B&W values. You may need to invert the color on some textures in order to get them to work right. Use RGB nodes to play with the colors until they look right. Look into how Blender uses Normal Maps. You sometimes have to do some strange things to get them to work right.

Lastly, if you want to use a PBR setup for your glossy (it's GORGEOUS), you'll want to look into how that's done in Blender (BlenderGuru has a recent tute on it). It's not terribly complicated, but it's also not terribly easy to figure out on your own.

Hope that helps!